# Pipe find list of files into xargs gzip and pipe again into pigz

Tags: files, tar, gzip

I need to find files newer than x days, and then turn it into a gzip, but I want to do it using pigz.

For now I'm now doing it the slow way; this works:

```
find /path/to/src -type f -mtime -90 | xargs tar -zcf archive.tar.gz
```

But `pigz` is tremendously faster, so I want to run this gzip using pigz instead. I tried this but it isn't working:

```
find /path/to/src -type f -mtime -90 | xargs tar -zcf | pigz > archive.tar.gz
```

It returns an error because I just guessed what to do (and tried a couple ways):

```
tar (child): /path/to/src: Cannot open: Is a directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

How to take the first line that works and pipe that into pigz?

Comment: Worth noting: I added `-type f ` because if you don't and the directory was modified in the last `n` days then it will include whole directories that may contain files inside that were not modified in the last `n` days.

Comment: Is this GNU tar? If so, you can just use `tar -I pigz` instead of piping to `pigz` again.

Comment: Do you really get `/path/to/src: Cannot open: Is a directory` *with* `-type f`?

Comment: Note that `xargs` may run `tar` several times (this is kinda the _point_ of `xargs`, to overcome the fact that command lines can grow too big sometimes). When it does, it would overwrite the existing archive that it just created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU tar on any shell that supports [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) (e.g. bash, ksh, zsh):

```
tar cf archive.tar.gz -I pigz --null -T <(find /path/to/src  -type f -mtime -90 -print0)
```

This uses `pigz` to do the compression, and takes the (NUL-separated) list of files to include in the archive from the output of `find ... -print0`, via the `-T` or `--files-from=FILE` option and process substitution.

Alternatively, if you are using a minimalist POSIX-features-only shell (e.g. ash or dash, or bash running as  `/bin/sh` or with `--posix` or `set -o posix` or with the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable set) you can pipe a NUL-separated list of filenames into GNU tar.  The `-` following the `-T` option tells tar to read the file list from stdin.

```
find /path/to/src  -type f -mtime -90 -print0 | tar cf archive.tar.gz -I pigz --null -T -
```

Either of these work with any valid filename, even those containing spaces, newlines and shell metacharacters.  It also avoids the problem of too-many-filenames mentioned by @Kusalananda in his comment.

BTW, you may want to investigate using [pixz](https://github.com/vasi/pixz) instead of `pigz`.  It does [xz](https://tukaani.org/xz/) compression (which generally does much better compression than gzip, but is slower), and pixz will add an index to speed up extraction of specific files if it detects tar-like input.   BTW, both `pixz` and `xz-utils` are packaged for most common Linux distribtions so should be easy to install.

Comment: I get this error.     `sh: syntax error near unexpected token '('

Comment: I tried both, and it returns the same `unexpected token`  result

Comment: I'm not using anything like that. And I copied and pasted it exactly like you posted.

Comment: Piping it worked, but since it doesn't preserve the modification time, I can't see if it's really the last 90 days most recent. Any way to verify that? Upvote and once I can verify it, will accept

Comment: nope just running on the command line. Nothing special, just copied and pasted. Regarding times when I extracted on my pc, all files have the date of extraction (now) and not the file dates.

Comment: default centos7.9/cloudlinux7.9. default shell. filesystem? Default. Versions? default. I didn't edit any of this stuff.

Comment: Actually, what the definition of "default" is, is the configuration when you do a vanilla setup. It means exactly what I said. Cloudlunx IS centos, it has no effect on your command.

Comment: Did you downvote?

Comment: someone downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming GNU or libarchive's `tar`:

```
find /path/to/src -type f -mtime -90 -print0 |
  tar -cf - --no-recursion --null -T - |
  pigz > archive.tar.gz
```

(`--no-recursion` not strictly necessary here as files reported by `find` are meant not to be of type *directory*).

Don't use `xargs` (which anyway can only be used on `find`'s output if you use `-0` and `find`'s `-print0`) as it could end up running more than one `tar` so you'd end up with the archive containing only the last batch.

Here, we're passing the list of files to `tar` directly via a pipe with `-T -` so there's no limit on how many files may be passed that way. That also means `tar` can start archiving the files as soon as they're found.

`star` ([@schily](/users/120884/schily)'s (RIP) `tar`) also has built-in `find` functionality:

```
star cf - -find /path/to/src -type f -mtime -90 |
  pigz > archive.tar.gz
```

Though, you can also take the same approach as for the other two above with this syntax:

```
find /path/to/src -type f -mtime -90 -print0 |
  star cf - -read0 list=- |
  pigz > archive.tar.gz
```

`tar` is a very unportable command. Even the tar format**s** are unportable. [X/Open / SUSv2 used to specify a `tar` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/intro.html) (and `cpio`), but they eventually gave up on it as it was impossible to conciliate the `tar`s from different vendors, and instead POSIX / SUS came up with `pax` as a replacement for both.

`pax` takes the list of files from stdin, but unfortunately, newline delimited instead of NUL delimited which means it can't archive arbitrary file names, though some `pax` implementations support a `-0` extension for that (`find`'s `-print0` is also not POSIX though can be replaced with `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +`). So, with those:

```
find /path/to/src -type f -mtime -90 -print0 |
  pax -0w |
  pigz > archive.tar.gz
```

(note that the default output format is undefined per POSIX which is another weakness of `pax`. Its worst weakness being its very low adoption).

Comment: Nice answer! Let me study up on what you wrote. Always like recommendations of new tools to make life easier too